# Prepared Statement does not insert

Tags: oracle, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

I am new to JDBC and trying following code. Could not find the error in it:

```
try{     
        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into create_request values((select count(reqno) from create_request)+1,?,?,?,?,?)");
        stmt.setString(1,obj_Leaverequest.getUser_name());
        stmt.setString(2,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Type());
        stmt.setInt(3,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Units());
        stmt.setString(4,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Reason());
        stmt.setString(5,"pending");
        count=stmt.executeUpdate();
        if(count>0){
            status=true;
        }
    }
```

**Update**:
If I replace my code like this it works:

```
String sqQuery="insert into create_request values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(sqQuery);
        stmt.setString(1,"(select count(reqno) from create_request)+1");
        stmt.setString(2,obj_Leaverequest.getUser_name());
        stmt.setString(3,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Type());
        stmt.setInt(4,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Units());
        stmt.setString(5,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Reason());
        stmt.setString(6,"pending");
```

Getters are working fine, I could print their values. I guess I am wrong with the query.  Please point out my mistake. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to commit the connection or use transaction.

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan Couldnt get u . can u pls tel me briefly? Should i commit the insert statement?

Comment: Place `con.commit();` after `executeUpdate();`. See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29

Comment: @kordirko i couldnt add the row still. have i witten the query correctly?

Comment: Define "I couldn't". What happens precisely? My guess is that you're getting an exception. But since we don't know what you put in the catch clause, you could have ignored it.

Comment: @JBNizet i left my catch block empty . updated my question could u pls review it

Comment: Have you got any exception ? Please show the part of code where you are catching exceptions (`catch( Exception ex ) { .... } )`

Comment: You left your catch block empty. That means that if an exception occurs, you can't even notice it. NEVER leave a catch block empty. Add the following lines to your catch block: `e.printStackTrace(); throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Comment: Insert, Update and Delete statement will not commit unless u call connection.commit(). Check catch block for any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sqQuery="insert into create_request values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(sqQuery);
        stmt.setString(1,"(select count(reqno) from create_request)+1");
        stmt.setString(2,obj_Leaverequest.getUser_name());
        stmt.setString(3,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Type());
        stmt.setInt(4,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Units());
        stmt.setString(5,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Reason());
        stmt.setString(6,"pending");
```

Check for the "?" prepared statements index . You have 6 , but you need only 5

Hope  this helps